# Question about identification map

Tags: general-topology

I've got a question to the theorem below:

> Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be an onto map. If $f$ maps open sets of $X$ to open sets of $Y$, then $f$ is an identification map.

If I got the idea right, we should prove that: $U$ is open in Y $\Leftrightarrow f^{-1}(U)$ open in X.

It's easy to prove from right to left but the reverse is not clear because the open map is not always continuous. Did I miss something or the theorem admits that f is continous?

Comment: There are open surjecive maps that aren't continuous (for instance, the inverse of a continuous bijection that isn't a homeomorphism), and if $f$ isn't continuous then there is an open $U$ in $Y$ such that $f^{-1}[U]$ isn't open. So the terminological issue exists and is unsolvable: if there's the implicit assumption that $f$ is continuous, then the statement is true, if there isn't, then it's false.

Comment: @Sassatelli Giulio
 Agreed, thanks.